# What is the low-level trigger for Windows Click events

Tags: windows, winforms

The standard sequence of events to trigger a mouse click in Windows is documented here:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx)

Essentially it is:

> 1. MouseDown event.
> 2. Click event.
> 3. MouseClick event.
> 4. MouseUp event.

However, I have a control which is altering the sequence of events by capturing events on its children (to implement dragging).  That means that the full sequence might not execute, e.g. currently I have a button which sees a MouseDown event, but no MouseUp event when the mouse is clicked.

Therefore the question is, what actually triggers the click at a low-level?  Does it need a `MouseDown` followed by a `MouseUp`.  Will a `MouseUp` on its own be sufficient?  Are there any other considerations?

Comment: If you do not implement the given flow many applications will have problems. Imagine app that listens to mouse down event.

Comment: @Andrey I'm not asking how to implement a particular sequence.  The sequence already exists and is out of my control.  I'm looking for details of what happens at a low-level so I can work around it.

Comment: The order says it all: you can't get a Click without having a MouseDown first.  And, a Click happens before a MouseDown so it does not even need a MouseUp.

Comment: @Brad Rem No. Click happens after MouseDown. This is based on the documentation and experience.

Comment: Yes, you're right: Click won't fire until a MouseDown is received but it's also true that Click won't fire unless MouseDown is received, so that has to happen.  I think the point is that when you do a MouseDown, your control captures the mouse so that when you MouseUp, it can send those other messages to the control. If you're trying to only use MouseUp, it probably means that some other control (or no control) has captured the mouse. Have you tried manipulating the mouse capture? I wonder if that would be possible.

Comment: Exactly right...another control has grabbed the Capture, in this case for implementing drag functionality.  I want to be able to still have clicks if there isn't actually a drag, which is why I need to understand what happens if parts of the sequence vary.

Comment: It sounds like you have a button that you can either drag or click? If so, in the DragLeave and/or QueryContinueDrag events can you check to see if the drag was cancelled and if so then manually fire your OnClick event handler for the button?

Comment: Sadly it's much more complicated than that.  I have a control with multiple child controls, including the button I want to click, and the drag functionality is custom implemented.  Therefore I'm just trying to understand the Click operation before tackling the wider issues.